# How to resolve Seagate USB 3.0 hard drive not being properly recognized by FreeBSD 10.3?

Tags: unix, freebsd

FreeBSD version: 10.3 Seagate drive model: SRD00F1 USB 3.0 Adapter: Insignia USB 3.0 PCIe Host Card (NS-PCCUP53)

When I reboot with the drive already attached, it is not seen. But, when I attach the drive, I see the following in the dmesg.today:

```
ugen5.2: at usbus5
umass0: on usbus5
umass0: SCSI over Bulk-Only; quirks = 0x0100
umass0:5:0:-1: Attached to scbus5
da0 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus5 target 0 lun 0
da0: Fixed Direct Access SPC-4 SCSI device
da0: Serial Number NA7WF86H
da0: 40.000MB/s transfers
da0: 953869MB (1953525167 512 byte sectors)
da0: quirks=0x2
ugen5.2: at usbus5 (disconnected)
umass0: at uhub5, port 2, addr 2 (disconnected)
da0 at umass-sim0 bus 0 scbus5 target 0 lun 0
da0: s/n NA7WF86H detached
(da0:umass-sim0:0:0:0): Periph destroyed
usb_alloc_device: set address 2 failed (USB_ERR_IOERROR, ignored)
usbd_setup_device_desc: getting device descriptor at addr 2 failed, USB_ERR_IOERROR
usbd_req_re_enumerate: addr=2, set address failed! (USB_ERR_IOERROR, ignored)
usbd_setup_device_desc: getting device descriptor at addr 2 failed, USB_ERR_IOERROR
usbd_req_re_enumerate: addr=2, set address failed! (USB_ERR_IOERROR, ignored)
usbd_setup_device_desc: getting device descriptor at addr 2 failed, USB_ERR_IOERROR
usbd_req_re_enumerate: addr=2, set address failed! (USB_ERR_IOERROR, ignored)
usbd_setup_device_desc: getting device descriptor at addr 2 failed, USB_ERR_IOERROR
usbd_req_re_enumerate: addr=2, set address failed! (USB_ERR_IOERROR, ignored)
usbd_setup_device_desc: getting device descriptor at addr 2 failed, USB_ERR_IOERROR
ugen0.2: at usbus0 (disconnected)
uhub_reattach_port: could not allocate new device
usbd_req_re_enumerate: addr=1, set address failed! (USB_ERR_IOERROR, ignored)
usbd_setup_device_desc: getting device descriptor at addr 1 failed, USB_ERR_IOERROR
usb_alloc_device: Failure selecting configuration index 0:USB_ERR_TIMEOUT, port 2, addr 1 (ignored)
ugen0.2: at usbus0
ugen0.2: at usbus0 (disconnected)
usbd_req_re_enumerate: addr=1, set address failed! (USB_ERR_IOERROR, ignored)
usbd_setup_device_desc: getting device descriptor at addr 1 failed, USB_ERR_IOERROR
usb_alloc_device: Failure selecting configuration index 0:USB_ERR_TIMEOUT, port 2, addr 1 (ignored)
ugen0.2: at usbus0
ugen0.2: at usbus0 (disconnected)
usb_alloc_device: Failure selecting configuration index 0:USB_ERR_TIMEOUT, port 2, addr 1 (ignored)
ugen0.2: at usbus0
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest to ask at one of FreeBSD's mailing lists https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/eresources-mail.html or the forum https://forums.freebsd.org/ FreeBSD developers seem to be much more active there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the PCIe slot, then swapping out the USB 3.0 card with the exact same model did not help. I then tried disabling the on-board USB (2.0), and this resolved my issue. There appears to be a conflict with USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 with FreeBSD.